# How to avoid transliteration of Russian text in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, russian

Using TexShop on Mac OS I try to compile a code:

```
 \setupbodyfont[dejavu]
 \enableregime[utf]
 \mainlanguage[russian]

 \starttext
 Немного русского текста для пробы.
 \stoptext
```

But it gives me a transliterated page

[image: transliterated text]

Is there is a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you using MkII or MkIV? What version of ConTeXt are using.

Comment: @Aditya mtx-context | main context file: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/context.mkiv mtx-context | current version: 2013.05.28 00:36

Comment: @Aditya I tried both in TeXShop when  run in ConTeXt it gives me transliteration, when I run ConTeXt(LuaTex) there is absolutely no text on the page, just number of the page and a dot of the end of sentence.

Comment: I don't know why, but after removing `.mp` and `syntax.gz` files it was fixed. File was produced with correct Russian in ConTeXt(LuaTex) for the font `dejavu`. For other fonts situation remains as it was described above. Any ideas?

Comment: This works correctly with a recent [context minimals](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone) ConTeXt MkIV 2014.03.28. I don't have access to TL2013, so cannot check why the test file fails there.

Comment: @Aditya ok. Tank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transliterated text is a "symptom" of using 8-bit ConTeXt MkII (pdfTeX) without setting up the fonts properly. Unicode letters are mapped to 256 glyphs and unless you switch the encoding to T2A, you'll get T1/EC encoding with the Latin alphabet.

Here's a proper MkII setup using Gentium:

```
\usetypescriptfile[type-gentium]
\usetypescript[gentium][t2a]
\setupbodyfont[gentium]
\enableregime[utf-8]
\mainlanguage[russian]

\starttext
Немного русского текста для пробы.
\stoptext
```

However I would strongly advise you to try to use MkIV (LuaTeX) for Russian. In MkIV you don't need to use `\enableregime` since the encoding is UTF-8 by default already.

The reason why you get a blank page is again because of the wrong font setup. The default Latin Modern font doesn't contain Cyrillic glyphs, so you basically get "empty glyphs" from LM. If you don't properly set up another font, for example if you try to use `\setupbodyfont[nonexistentname]`, ConTeXt doesn't throw any warnings, just silently ignores the switch and sticks with LM without displaying any Cyrillic.

If you switch to another font that lacks Cyrillic support, you'll get the same result as with LM: lots of missing glyphs. A notable example might be `\setupbodyfont[times]` switching to [TeX Gyre Termes](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/termes) which used to work in the beginning, but the Cyrillic support was later removed due to very bad quality and nobody willing to step in yet to fix it. The same is true for the whole TeX Gyre font family.

A working MkIV setup would be:

```
\setupbodyfont[gentium]
\mainlanguage[russian]

\starttext
Немного русского текста для пробы.
\stoptext
```

[image: "Немного русского текста для пробы." in Gentium]

You can replace `[gentium]` with any font that ConTeXt supports via typescripts as long as that font has support for Cyrillic. Examples include `[dejavu]`, `[iwona]`, `[antykwa-torunska]`, ...

If you want to use a font that's not predefined in ConTeXt, you either need to write your own [typescript](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Simple_Typescript_Example) for it or use a `simplefonts` module written by Wolfgang that has recently been integrated into ConTeXt. The following example uses Comic Sans installed by the system, but `\definefontfamily` only works with TeX Live 2014 or the standalone distribution:

```
\definefontfamily[comic][serif][Comic Sans MS]
\setupbodyfont[comic]
\mainlanguage[russian]

\starttext
Немного русского текста для пробы.
\stoptext
```

[image: "Немного русского текста для пробы." in Comic Sans]

The example won't work with TL 2013. If you cannot afford to upgrade your distribution and want to use system fonts, you need to either write a typescript or load the `simplefonts` module. But your example with dejavu should work out-of-the-box even with TL 2013. Just remove `\enableregime` and make sure that you compile the example with LuaTeX, not with pdfTeX.

Comment: Comic Sans? Gasp! `;-)`

Comment: You are right. I added a PNG with the result to make it nicer `:)` (Seriously though, I didn't have that many "universally available" system fonts and this one seemed 'just right for the purpose'.)

Comment: @MojcaMiklavec Thank you for the great detailed answer!. :)